# Trouble making two Docker containers talk via TLS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two Docker containers (app_1 and app_2, written in Python) which use FastAPI to expose a simple get endpoint. I have generated self signed certs. Both containers can be accessed via a browser on TLS. I start these using:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I have verified that both app_1 and app_2 are in the same Docker network.

When app_1 makes the get() call to app_2, it gets "connection refused."

Here are the files:

app_1.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import ssl
import uvicorn 
import requests
import time
import urllib3
import sched 

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello from app_1"}


def make_request():
    url = "http://app_2:8002"

    response = requests.get(url) 
    if response.status_code == 200:
       print(response.json())
    else:
        print(f"Request failed status code: {response.status_code}") 


scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def make_rest_call_periodically():
    make_request()

    scheduler.enter(10, 10, make_rest_call_periodically)

scheduler.enter(10, 10, make_rest_call_periodically)

scheduler.run() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn 
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=443, ssl_keyfile="/app/certs/client.key", ssl_certfile="/app/certs/client.crt")
```

App_2.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import ssl
import uvicorn 
import requests
import time
import urllib3

app = FastAPI()

#urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

@app.get('/')
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello from app_2"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn 

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=443, ssl_keyfile="/app/certs/client2.key", ssl_certfile="/app/certs/client2.crt")
```

Dockerfile.app_1

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY app_1.py .

EXPOSE 443 

CMD [ "python", "app_1.py" ]
```

Dockerfile.app_2

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY app_2.py .

EXPOSE 443 

CMD [ "python", "app_2.py" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app_1:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app_1 
    ports:
      - 8001:443
    container_name: app_1  
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/app/certs 
    networks:
      - my-network  

  app_2:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app_2 
    ports:
      - 8002:443
    container_name: app_2  
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/app/certs 
    networks:
      - my-network  

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

requirements.txt:

```
fastapi==0.68.1
uvicorn==0.15.0
requests==2.30.0
```

Comment: I just skimmed your question, but here is one remark: it seems both app_1 and app_2 are publically exposed (`ports:`) and HTTPS-aware ( ssl options), while app_2 looks like an internal service (thence, it should *not* be exposed publically, and it may suffice for it to listen to mere HTTP requests ?)

Comment: Then it is very plausible that the issue comes from your URL: you wrote `http://app_2:8002` but in your docker-compose.yml, 8002 is the external port, not the port from the inner Docker network → you could just try `https://app_2` (while `http://app_2:8080` would be more idiomatic for an inner service).

Comment: Ah! Thank you! That made some progress. Now the error is that the cert validity failed, which must mean the two are talking. So apparently you nailed it!